# Play a youtube url in android

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-videoview

I have a fragment and a videoview is present inside that fragment.I have a you tube url for video.
I tried videoview as well as webview. But it is not working.
How i should play that video inside that layout?

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use normal a `webview` and everything will be fine.

**Try this**: (**Tested and works**)

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        try {
            Log.e("Status", "tried url");
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://youtube.com/xxxxxxxxx");  

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("Status", "In Run():");
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Status", "exception");
        }       
    }       
}).start();
```

Comment: where does the object of handler created?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

It provides you with an efficient YouTube Player view (or even better - a [Fragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment)) for embedding in your app that you can control programatically.