# How to play YouTube video in android app

Tags: java, android

I want to play YouTube videos inside my android app. How can I do it without downloading the YouTube API?
I found the following code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193615/play-a-youtube-url-in-android) on stack overflow:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

                try {
                    Log.e("Status", "tried url");
                    myWebView.loadUrl(icobj.video_URL);  

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.e("Status", "In Run():");
                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Status", "exception");
                }       
            }       
        }).start();
```

But "handler cannot be resolved to a variable" error is shown.  Please help!!

Comment: Firstly, please show us your efforts (not someone elses). Secondly, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551203/3436942 or read the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Answer (score -1):

with a quick view at your code, I would suggest that you should check which type of variable the handler is and whether you have imported and created it.

If that does not work, you could have a look at the [exo player](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) from google , which I am using for my video related projects.